# Broken image in selenium initialization error

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYeAq.png)

I am trying to run broken image code for www.google.com. I'm getting an initialization error at run time. While compiling the code I'm getting an error at line 55.

The error is only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang .Iterable. failure trace at run time are:

(1.)java.lang.Exception:Method SetUp() should be static.

(2.) java.lang. Exception :Method tear Down() should be static.

Code is given below for the reference, I am also attaching the screenshot for reference.

**CODE**

[image]

```
 package fb_project;


    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
    import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.junit.AfterClass;
    import org.junit.BeforeClass;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    import java.util.List;

       /**
      * @author Prerna
      *
      */
      public class Broken_image {

      /**
     * @param args
     */

        private WebDriver driver;
        private int invalidImageCount;

        @BeforeClass
        public void setUp() {

    String exePathGecko=("C:\\Users\\Prerna\\Downloads        \\geckodriver.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",exePathGecko);
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://google.com");
        }
   @Test
        public void validateInvalidImages() {
            try {
                invalidImageCount = 0;
                List imagesList = (List) driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
                System.out.println("Total no. of images are " + imagesList.size());
                for (WebElement imgElement : imagesList) {
                    if (imgElement != null) {
                        verifyimageActive(imgElement);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Total no. of invalid images are "   + invalidImageCount);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        @AfterClass
        public void tearDown() {
            if (driver != null)
                driver.quit();
        }



    public void verifyimageActive(WebElement imgElement) {
                try {
                    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(imgElement.getAttribute("src"));
                    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) client.execute(request);
                    // verifying response code he HttpStatus should be 200 if not,
                    // increment as invalid images count
                    if (response.getStatus().getCode() != 200)
                        invalidImageCount++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The image you have attached shows a different runtime error than the error you are asking about.

Comment: Please tell about the error and  how to solve those issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing error because you have imported wrong `List` package
Change

```
import java.awt.List;
```

To

```
import java.util.List;
```

And change  your syntax to -

```
 List<WebElement>imagesList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
```

Comment: i have tried with your idea also. but getting the same error at run time ,i.e. initialization error.please let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `List` from [java.awt.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/List.html) witch is not implementing `Iterable<E>` interface. This is also why you can't use `imagesList.size()`. Instead use [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
List<WebElement> imagesList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
```

Comment: i have tried with this changes also , but getting the same error of initialization.please suggest me how to solve it?

Comment: @agusta Delete `import java.awt.List;`. and restart your developing platform.

Comment: i have already deleted the ,          import java.awt.List;   i am attaching the screen shot above for new issue .kindly go through it and let me know.

Comment: getting two failure trace as : (1.) java.lang.Exception:Method SetUp() should be static.    (2.)java.lang.Exception :Method tear Down()should be static.

Comment: @agusta The error message is quite clear: `setUp()` and `tearDown()` should be static `public static void setUp()`

Answer (score 0):

/**
 * 
 */
           package fb_project;

```
       import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
       import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
       import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
       import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponse;
       import org.junit.AfterClass;
       import org.junit.BeforeClass;
       import org.junit.Test;
       import org.openqa.selenium.By;
       import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
       import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
       import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

      import java.util.List;
      /**
      * @author Prerna
          *
       */
             public class Broken_image {

            /**
            * @param args
            */




              private static WebDriver driver;
               private int invalidImageCount;

           @BeforeClass
            public static void setUp(){

            String exePathGecko=("C:\\Users\\Prerna\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",exePathGecko);
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void validateInvalidImages() {
        try {
            invalidImageCount = 0;



            List<WebElement> imagesList = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));


            System.out.println("Total no. of images are " + imagesList.size());
            for (WebElement imgElement : imagesList) {
                if (imgElement != null) {
                    verifyimageActive(imgElement);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Total no. of invalid images are "   + invalidImageCount);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @AfterClass

    public static void tearDown()
    {
        if (driver != null)
            driver.quit();
    }

    public void verifyimageActive(WebElement imgElement) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(imgElement.getAttribute("src"));
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) client.execute(request);
            // verifying response code he HttpStatus should be 200 if not,
            // increment as invalid images count
            if (response.getStatus().getCode() != 200)
                invalidImageCount++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```